# Applying Stone Weierstrass to this isometry of $C^\ast$-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, c-star-algebras

I proved the following theorem but I'd like to confirm the last part of my proof. Statement:

Let $A$ be a non-zero commutative $C^\ast$ algebra. Then $\varphi : A \to C_0 (\Omega(A))$ defined by $a \mapsto \widehat{a}$ (Gelfand representation) is an isometric $\ast$ isomorphism.

I had no trouble showing that it is an isometric $\ast$-homomorphism. Then to argue why it is surjective I want to use Stone Weierstrass to show that $\overline{\varphi (A) }= C_0(\Omega(A))$. So I argue as follows:

(i) $\varphi (A)$ vanishes nowhere: Let $\tau \in \Omega(A)$. Then $\tau$ is a character and therefore by definition non-zero hence there exists $a \in A$ with $\tau (a) \neq 0$. Hence $\widehat{a}(\tau) \neq 0$.

(ii) $\varphi (A)$ separates points: Let $\tau, \tau' \in \Omega (A)$. Then $\tau - \tau'$ is also a character hence by definition non-zero. Hence there exists $a \in A$ with $(\tau - \tau')(a) \neq 0$. Hence $\widehat{a}(\tau) \neq \widehat{a}(\tau')$.

Is this really correct? Saying something follows from the definition seems a little too easy.

Comment: Some excercises are done to just check definitions.

Comment: Sure but just because some exercise are only there to check definitions doesn't mean that this one is.

Comment: No, $\tau - \tau'$ is generally not a character. $$(\tau(x) - \tau'(x))(\tau(y)-\tau'(y)) = \tau(x)\tau(y) + \tau'(x)\tau'(y) - \tau(x)\tau'(y) - \tau(y)\tau'(x) \neq \tau(x)\tau(y) - \tau'(x)\tau'(y)$$ usually. But you don't need that $\tau-\tau'$ were a character. All you need is that characters are _maps_, and what it means for two maps to be different.